# Modify Python cmd module's history on Windows

Tags: python, python-cmd

My Python program has an interactive command line implemented with cmd module.

How can I add commands to cmd history (so that it can be reached by cursor-up shortcut)?

Please, note the program runs on Windows so readline library tricks aren't relevant.

Comment: Did you try pyreadline?

Comment: readline implementation for Windows, looks promising... I'll look into it. Thanks.